# AS3 gotoAndStop getting stuck

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have a very simple `gotoAndStop(100);` in the first frame that seems to get stuck on frame 50. It has no problem going anywhere before it, but after, it fails. There is nothing but a stop(); command on frame 50, and even if I remove all actions, it still doesn't work. What could be wrong?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Any chance you could post a source file with the issue?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Sure, thank you! [fla + swf](http://www.filefactory.com/file/4lhmxxh7uj8f/n/flash_rar)

Answer (score 3):

Your goToAndStop (100) method is inside an if statement:

```
 if( getVal('v') != undefined ) {
     trace( "Skip to last scene" );
     gotoAndStop(100);
 }
```

If you try to trace getVal ('v') in that point you'll see that is undefined. So the if never executes, and the goToAndPlay will never be triggered.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention with the file that it should execute on the second run only (assuming you clicked all the way to the last frame). 'v' is defined by then.